# Setting CTCP in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, connection, tcp

I have been looking for a way to set Congestion Provider to CTCP for the majority of my connection on Windows 10 Home.

I have tried what is listed [here](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1271672-set-nettcpsetting-still-incomplete-code-in-windows-10/) but in nothing works.

Properties are protected and I was not even able to run Get-NetTransportFilter to understand which is the current situation.

Any ideas? 
Was anyone able to find the corresponding registry keys? 
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: I seem to recall Win 10 now defaults to CUBIC, like Linux and macOS have been using for some time now. Is there a particular reason you want to regress to CTCP instead of CUBIC?

Comment: As far as I have understood, there are multiple defaults depending on the connection. In particular the compat profile works with newreno. I might be wrong but ctcp appears to be more efficient than that. Feel free to correct me and give me a better understanding of the topic. In the mean time thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Save the below into Notepad and save it as a `.reg` file.
Then import and run / reboot and it should change it to CTCP.
This was working for Windows 8, but it still works on Windows 10.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi\{eb004a03-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}\0]
"0200"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"1700"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```